# Batch rename folders with illegal characters * and :

Tags: batch, rename

I want to move thousands of folders and files from an old to a new storage system with Windows 2008 R2. Obviously a user with MAC OS has named hundreds of folders with characters - * and : - that Windows cannot read or rename, because it notices folders and files with illegal characters as invalid. In MAC OS these folders and files are valid.

So how can I batch rename these folders, in order to copy all the data to my new storage system within my Windows Server 2008 R2? Maybe with a renaming tool in MAC OS? Maybe with a renaming tool in Windows, that can read folders with illegal characters? Which one of them can search for such strange illegal characters, because searching with * finds all of the files and folders and : can also cause problems when searching.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I am reasonaly sure that OXS ships with `find`. As for the asterix, escape it to feed to to find. If you do not the shell will expand it.

Comment: I guess it's impossible in Windows.  In OS X, `find -name "*\**"` should find all files whose names contain `*`, and `find -name "*[*:]*"` should find all files whose names contain `*` or `:`

Comment: Thanks Scott, this works fine, but how can I rename all folders containing - * and : - ?

Answer (score 0):

Prefacing file with `\\?\` turns off filename checking.

```
copy \\?\c:\windows\win.ini \\?\c:\
```